# Free and secure PHP user management system

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for an secure php usermanagement system. It should be just the logics, so no markup or too much content (like messages etc.). I know I could just build it myself, but I doubt if it will be the most effecient usermanangement system.

The system should be at least

- able to verify if the user is human
- very secure (security against hacks, but also protect the users from their stupidity)
- effecient (number of users will start at 1k and from then grow exponentially to around 100k)
- capable of handling roles and capabilities

You guys got any recommandations?

Comment: No recommendation, but there are lots of lists for such things: http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/user-management/ - Albeit you have too many requirements (unsatisfiable and overstated).

Answer (score 19):

You can use any of the following scripts:

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/phploginsystemw/  (Login with 5 levels of security)
2. http://usercake.com/
3. http://www.downscripts.com/user-management-script_php-script.html
4. http://userpie.com/
5. http://gscripts.net/free-php-scripts/Login_Management/PHP_Login_Script/details.html
6. http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-php-user-management-script-log-me-in/

Comment: Thank you, that is a nice list. I awarded you the bounty, but since I am not the author of the original question, I cannot mark it as an answer.

Comment: Good links, i would like to add one more in the above list.
it has AdmitLte, Codeigntier HMVC, responsive, email templates, permission and many other features

http://www.webprojectbuilder.com/item/user-login-and-management

Answer (score 3):

You should probably take a look at this: 
http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/php/scripts-programs/user-management/
I have use this before:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phploginsystemw/
worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [drupal](http://drupal.org/). It is a framework with modules for this stuff. You will be able to get away with very minimal coding.